# How to add a bunch of words to my custom dictionary in word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, dictionary

I have a list of 3000 words and they are custom words between legal, scientific, and common errors I want to add it to my custom dictionary and want to add in one step.
how to do that please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save your list of words using Notepad as a .DIC file.

Ensure you select Unicode from the Encoding dropdown list next to the save button.

Presuming that you are using Windows 7, place your new .dic file in the folder which corresponds with C:\Users{your username}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UProof.

Word 2007: Open Word and Click the Microsoft Office Button and then Click Options.
Word 2010: Open Word and Click File, then Options.

Select Proofing.

Click Custom Dictionaries.

Click Add...

Select your file and Click Open.

If you want the new dictionary to be default, highlight it and Click Change Default.

Click Ok.

Comment: Note: If you get a "Files without Unicode encoding can't be added to the dictionary list. Save the file as a Unicode file and add it to the dictionary list" error, make sure the dictionary file has UCS-2 LE BOM encoding.